# Is there a performance difference between background size cover and background size 100% auto?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I know what the difference is between `background-size: cover` and `background-size: 100% auto`. I was just curious if there is a performance difference between the two and if that difference is big enough to prefer one of the two.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not too broad. All I'm asking is if there's a performance difference. How is it not specific?

Comment: Have you tested....it could be dependent on too many things...the image, the CPU and many others..and "which is preferred" is asking for opinions and so is still off-topic.

Comment: @Paulie_D Is it too broad? It is just a question about performance comparison and I don't think that the CPU would have such an impact to these results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `background-size: cover`. I've had very bad performance experience with it, especially for long lists that scroll.

If you use it as a background image for your browser viewport, then use it in this fashion:

https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property/

If you use `background-size: cover` e.g. for backgrounds of tiles, of which you may have many, then it's wiser to just use `background-size: $tile-width $tile-height;`.

Good luck!